# Call implemented interfaces from service?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Not sure if this is possible, but I would like the service to call implemented methods like below.

Prism has an `INavigatingAware` that viewmodels can implement. I want to follow the same pattern and add my own interface like below.

Using Prism and Xamarin.

```
public interface ILoginAware
{
    void LoggedIn(Customer customer);
    void LoggedOut();
}

public class ProfilePageViewModel : ILoginAware
{
    public void LoggedIn(Customer customer) => ShowAuthenticatedViews(customer);
    public void LoggedOut() => ShowNotAuthenticatedViews();
}

public class CustomerService
{
    public void Login()
    {
        var customer = DoLogin();
        // How to call ProfilePageViewModel.LoggedIn(customer) from here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism doesn't know about your interface. You would need to implement your own navigation service to achieve what you want.